# How to reference ubuntu MATLAB runtime libraries in C#?

Tags: c#, matlab, ubuntu

I have a C# program that uses the MWARRAY.dll from MATLAB. I am trying to run this program on Ubuntu with mono. But, it keeps saying the MWArray.dll was not found. I have install Matlab runtime on my Ubuntu machine. I wanted to know how to reference Matlab ubuntu libraries in C# code. Is it even possible?

Comment: What does your `DllImport` look like? For linux usually you need to reference a `.so` file instead of a `.dll`...

Comment: it is using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays; I have the same .so file on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: how do I reference a .so file in my c# code?

Comment: Are you using `DllImport` or did you reference that library by "Add Reference"?

Comment: No I referenced that with Add Reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DLLmaps](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/) to map library names for specific operating systems. For example, you can put a line like `<dllmap dll="some.dll" target="libsome.so" os="!windows"/>` in your `/etc/mono/config` file and it will be mapped for every project.